# virtual keyboard ctrl button

Tags: keyboard, virtual

I want to ask why stack my CTRL button in the virtual keyboard. I am using C# code:
        keybd_event(ctrl, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);

```
 keybd_event(A, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Wait();
    keybd_event(ctrl, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(A, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

variables

```
public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; //Key down flag
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag
public const int A = 0x41; //A key code
public const int ctrl = 0xA2; //ctrl key code
```

When I execute code all time Ctrl button was press. I press right ctrl button in my keyboard and problem disappearing.

maybe somebody know how solve problem. When execute code CTRL button will not press.

Answer (score 1):

try using 0x0003 as keyup flag for ctrl/shift/alt

Comment: well basically he's using public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; as the keyup flag.. so a keyboard has two Ctrls, Shifts and Alts and just last night I was trying to add shift to my virtual keyboard but with 0x0002 it couldnt be released so I tried 0x0003 as keyup flag and it worked.. Basically use 0x0003 for Ctrl, Shift and Alt keyup flags since those buttons are x2 in a normal keyboard and 0x0001 and 0x0002 flags point to left/right button while 0x0003 releases them